# Openshift HTTP times out after 60 seconds

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, ibm-cloud

I have a server set up with Flask.
Everything works fine locally, HTTP requests can take longer than 60 seconds to resolve.

But when I deploy the server on Openshift, any request that takes longer than 60 seconds will time out automatically.

I have already changed the timeout on openshift to 10m, but that is not working. Any idea?

```
haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout: 10m
```

Comment: Could specify more information regarding the openshift environment? Like where is it running (cloud, which cloud, on-prem), could there be another proxy between the cluster's haproxy and you? Can you add the application yaml files (at least deployment, service, route)? Which version of openshift are you using? etc...

Comment: It is running on IBM Cloud and I am running v4.5.39. There is no proxy in-between. @NoamYizraeli

Comment: Is there a way to modify the following?
Raw

  timeout connect
  timeout client
  timeout client-fin
  timeout server
  timeout server-fin
  timeout http-request
  timeout http-keep-alive

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean haproxy timeout, which is set in the haproxy config file (which I'll need to see to be as specific as I can but currently my best bet is setting `timeout server` to a more suitable value). And if you're asking how to change the haproxy config file On IBM cloud I'm out of luck cause I'm not so familiar with IBM Cloud. If you do find a way to change the file and `timeout server` just isn't cutting it, I found a nice explanation [here](https://www.papertrail.com/solution/tips/haproxy-logging-how-to-tune-timeouts-for-performance/) on different timeout options

Comment: I've seen (on AWS at least), there can be additional complexities with the timeouts. For instance, on AWS, there is a timeout on the Load Balancer that HAProxy is unable to control. So I would check your cloud-specific infrastructure to ensure there aren't other factors affecting your timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the way I set up OpenShift. I am using VPC environment which has its own connection timeout:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/vpc?topic=vpc-advanced-traffic-management#connection-timeouts